# Recalculating condition in for loop or not

Tags: java

Say I have (Java)

```
String word = args[0];
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {}
```

I know the .length() method on a string isn't necessarily costly, but just to confirm: would this recalculate word.length() on each pass of the for loop? Would it be better to define

```
int length = word.length;
```

and use i < length as the condition in the loop?

Answer (score 3):

The length of the `String` is **NOT** calculated each time you call `word.length()`. That's because the `String` class stores the length as a field upon the creation.

**If you see the code for `length()` method of `java.lang.String` class, it only contains this:**

```
public int length() {
    return value.length;
}
```

---

And so doing

```
int length = word.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {}
```

Will have the same performance when done like this:

```
int length = word.length();
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {}
```

*Also note that the former code moves the call outside the loop which basically removes the need for the method call. However, that would be a trivial performance enhancement.*

Comment: Also, there is a good probability that the method will get inlined.

Answer (score 2):

Java strings are constant, and the length() method is implemented to be fast (unlike strlen in c). That code will be fine.

That said, one way to avoid this fear is counting to zero. It's marginally faster because you only make a single method call and comparisons to 0 are cheaper than non-zero. *Marginally* cheaper.

```
for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) ...
```

Another is using a [CharacterIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/CharacterIterator.html), but it's overkill for this:

```
 CharacterIterator iter = new StringCharacterIterator(word);
 for(char c = iter.first(); c != CharacterIterator.DONE; c = iter.next()) ...
```